# Toree on Jupyter for Spark 2.2.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, apache-toree

```
OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
Spark 2.2.0 (local)
Scala 2.11.8
```

I'm using `Jupyter` via my install of `anaconda3`. My understanding is that the latest production release of Toree does not support either Spark 2.0+ or Scala 11. However I have found several references ([1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOREE-336), [2](https://blog.thedataincubator.com/2017/04/spark-2-0-on-jupyter-with-toree/)) where you can clone `incubator-toree` from `github` and manually set the version of `Spark`.

In my mac terminal, this is the code I've used:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree
cd incubator-toree
```

Then, the line `make clean release APACHE_SPARK_VERSION=2.2.0` gives me the following error:

```
rm -r dist
rm: dist: No such file or directory
make: [clean-dist] Error 1 (ignored)
APACHE_SPARK_VERSION=2.2.0 VERSION=0.2.0.dev1-incubating IS_SNAPSHOT=true sbt clean
/bin/sh: sbt: command not found
make: *** [clean] Error 127
```

I'm looking for guidance around this error.

Comment: `sbt: command not found`... You didn't bother installing `sbt`, did you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the developer snapshots using by running following commands

```
pip install https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/toree/0.2.0/snapshots/dev1/toree-pip/toree-0.2.0.dev1.tar.gz
```

This version supports spark-2.2.0

Comment: if you experience timeout with that url, try this [Toree](https://anaconda.org/hyoon/toree). This works for me.

Comment: @ashwinids @jyu have you all had trouble running basic Spark Scala commands in Jupyter with this kernel? Simple things like `.toDF` and `$"columnName"` are throwing errors.